# Using an answer to comment on real answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

[This deleted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/140870/71820) was used to comment on the usefulness of the actual answers so was criticised and suggestion made that it should have been a comment, not an answer.

1. You need a reputation of 50+ to comment? so this may not be an option
2. A comment can only be applied to one answer?, whereas this 'answer' was commenting on the answers in general, not specific to one answer.

So if the facility is not there to make a general comment, is it fair to criticise the person for using an answer the way they did?

Comment: The person wasn't really being criticized (although the downvotes were a bit harsh) but gently reminded that the "Your Answer" box is for *answers* only. Objectively speaking, the person was saying *thanks* and not much else.

Comment: 1. For a comment of broad general scope, post it under the question, not under a particular answer, certainly not as an answer by itself. 2. Yes, one needs some rep for comment privilege. 3. Ask site related questions on [meta.english.se]

Comment: The 'answers in general' seem pretty similar, so a comment on the first given (and/or an upvote) would have been appropriate. And if it is considered imperative in the great scheme of things to convey one's appreciation, working **within the site's rules** would better achieve this end. The site's not perfect, but we've all had to go through the same frustrating kindergarten stage. A 50+ reputation is not too difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

What you and the original answerer seem not to have taken into account is that there is a *reason* why newcomers are not allowed to comment. Specifically, until you have been on here for a while, you are unlikely to grasp what makes SE different from other sites. This is not a forum, but a strict Q and A site. So no 'Thank you', no argument in the comments, no general discussion. Newcomers are not expected to grasp this immediately,so they are not allowed to comment till they have gained a bare minimum of rep [50 might take a day or two, depending on how well-considered your posts are].

And before saying "The site won't allow me to comment, so I shall post what would have been a comment in the box marked 'Your Answer'", is it really such a bad idea to stop and think it over? Too many flamewars as it is are caused by people who can type faster than they think.

Comment: Oh, it tries to be a "strict Q and A site", but in fact it's neither strict nor Q&A in practice. It's more or less chaotic.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You seem grumpy today. What's up?